# bind: dns_master_load: file format mismatch

Tags: bind, format

I have set a slave DNS server for `myzone.info` domain. After reloading bind 9.9.5 on Ubuntu, `syslog` gives the following messages:

```
Jul 13 17:12:14 dns2 named[18599]: dns_master_load: file format mismatch
Jul 13 17:12:14 dns2 named[18599]: zone myzone.info/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.myzone.info failed: not implemented
```

Please note our bind data file `/etc/bind/db.myzone.info` is as follows:

```
$TTL    8400

        IN      SOA     ns1.myzone.info. root.myzone.info. (
                     2016071149 
                           1200
                            600
                        1209600
                           3600 )
        IN      NS      ns1.myzone.info.
        IN      NS      ns2.myzone.info.
ns1     IN      A       154.34.25.22

ns2     IN      A       98.75.156.109
```

Please note our `named.conf` file is as follows:

```
zone "myzone.info" {

    type slave;
    file "/etc/bind/db.myzone.info";
    masters { 154.34.25.22; };
};
```

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: Your zone file should probably start with `@ IN SOA `

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you are probably migrating from the old bind and after restart the file is renamed to db-#hash#.

The solution is to add masterfile-format text; into your named.conf so it will look like

```
zone "myzone.info" {

    type slave;
    masterfile-format text;
    file "/etc/bind/db.myzone.info";
    masters { 154.34.25.22; };
};
```

and recreate the file db.myzone.info again and restart bind.